# Azure Ubuntu VM - Connect Button Disabled

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

I've created a VM of Ubuntu-16.04 LTS using Resource Manager. VM has been created successfully but the connect and start buttons are disabled. In tutorials, the connect button is already enabled once the VM is created.

Comment: What tutorials? Also this is a better question for superuser.com or one of those sites. No programming here...

Comment: Either superuser or serverfault. But not stackoverflow. And when you repost, include a screenshot of what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one of the following reasons:

- VM doesn't have a public IP address
- No GUI on the VM so you need to use SSH

Could also be access to the VM if you don't have the appropriate permissions.